# English equivalent to "My mother - sent me - to a private english teacher when I was a child"

Tags: verbs, expressions

In Spanish it's usual to use "send" when we express things like:

> My mother **sent me** to a private english teacher when I was a child.

Search engines just throw very very few examples related to this, so I'm suspecting it's not a proper or common way to say it in English, so which is it?

Comment: Your example is perfectly good English. (well, except we capitalize "English")

Comment: I'm wondering what kind of examples you are looking for. Examples of _send to_ used like this? There should be plenty. Examples of this exact specific situation you will find less, sometimes kids are not sent to private teachers, but to schools, maybe for different subjects, it may be the father doing the sending, or the parents together. In short, make sure that you search for _just the phrase_ you have doubts about.

Comment: As an example of my previous comment: [a Google search on "sent to school"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22sent%20to%20school%22) gives plenty of examples.

Comment: Right, I searched for "sent/send to private teacher" because and it didn't throw results, and I wasn't sure if the use of "sent to school" was extendable to a professional (instead of a physical place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is a perfectly fine way to express the idea, except, as @ThePhoton points out, "English" needs to be capitalized.

Another expression you could use is "My mother took me to a private English teacher." The difference would be that *took* indicates more active involvement in bringing you to the lessons.